# Ayuda si no encuentro valor en la tabla

Tags: php, mysql, buscador

hola amigos tengo una tabla catalogo

```
id    codigo   descripcion
01    12345     envase
02    12346     caja
```

y una tabla inventario

```
id    codigo   descripcion  marca
01    12345001  envase      dplast
```

Yo estoy haciendo un formulario de ingreso de nuevo inventario en donde con ayuda del  catalogo busco envase 12345 y luego cuando guarde quiero que se incremente a uno mas osea 12345001 siempre y cuando no existiera en la tabla inventario y si ya había 12345001 entonces que se incremente a 12345002, esta probando con esta sentencia pero solo me sale para incrementar mas no para aumentar:

```
if ("SELECT codigo FROM inventario WHERE substr(codigo,1,5)=$codigo ") {
$e=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT MAX(codigo) +1 max FROM detalleinventarioinicial  where substr(codigo,1,5)='$codigo' and idcolegio=$idcolegio GROUP by descripcion");
$d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($e);



mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO detalleinventarioinicial (idingreso,nro,codigo,descripcion,unidad,cantidad,marca,serie,color,tipo,procedencia,docingreso,numdocingreso,estado,observacion,idcolegio,idusuario,modificacion) VALUES ('$idingreso','$nro','$d[max]','$descripcion','$unidad','$cantidad','$marca','$serie','$color','$tipo','$procedencia','$docingreso','$numdocingreso','$estado','$observacion','$idcolegio','$idusuario','$modificacion')"); 


$_SESSION['message'] = "Registro Guardado"; 
header('location: inventario.php');
}
   else     {
$e=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT (codigo * 1000)+1   FROM detalleinventarioinicial  where substr(codigo,1,5)='$codigo' and idcolegio=$idcolegio GROUP by descripcion");
$d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($e);



mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO detalleinventarioinicial (idingreso,nro,codigo,descripcion,unidad,cantidad,marca,serie,color,tipo,procedencia,docingreso,numdocingreso,estado,observacion,idcolegio,idusuario,modificacion) VALUES ('$idingreso','$nro','$d','$descripcion','$unidad','$cantidad','$marca','$serie','$color','$tipo','$procedencia','$docingreso','$numdocingreso','$estado','$observacion','$idcolegio','$idusuario','$modificacion')"); 


$_SESSION['message'] = "Registro Guardado"; 
header('location: inventario.php');
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias pobar con:

```
       if(!mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO detalleinventarioinicial (idingreso,nro,codigo,descripcion,unidad,cantidad,marca,serie,color,tipo,procedencia,docingreso,numdocingreso,estado,observacion,idcolegio,idusuario,modificacion) VALUES ('$idingreso','$nro','{$codigo}001','$descripcion','$unidad','$cantidad','$marca','$serie','$color','$tipo','$procedencia','$docingreso','$numdocingreso','$estado','$observacion','$idcolegio','$idusuario','$modificacion')")){
    // El registro con el codigo 001 ya existe
    $e=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT MAX(codigo) +1 max FROM detalleinventarioinicial  where substr(codigo,1,5)='$codigo' and idcolegio=$idcolegio GROUP by descripcion");
    $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($e);

    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO detalleinventarioinicial (idingreso,nro,codigo,descripcion,unidad,cantidad,marca,serie,color,tipo,procedencia,docingreso,numdocingreso,estado,observacion,idcolegio,idusuario,modificacion) VALUES ('$idingreso','$nro','{$d['max']}','$descripcion','$unidad','$cantidad','$marca','$serie','$color','$tipo','$procedencia','$docingreso','$numdocingreso','$estado','$observacion','$idcolegio','$idusuario','$modificacion')");
    }
    //Si el registro no existia se guardo en el if
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Registro Guardado"; 

header('location: inventario.php');
```

Si el registro no existe lo inserta y redirecciona, si existe busca el valor mas alto le añade 1 y lo inserta, espero que te valga.

Comment: hola amigo Javier esta excelente tu ayuda pero cuando la he probado solo me funciona agregando el 001 y no aumenta uhm gracias de antemano parece que faltaria algun detalle .......

Comment: ah hice algo ortodoxo pero funciono nose si utilize buenas practicas pero esta de pelos, si funciona de repente a algún desamparado le sirva:

Answer (score 0):

buena esto me funciono en base a lo que me respondiste javier gracias hermano por ayudar a un alma perdida.....

```
<?php 



     $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['codigo']);
       $c= $_POST['codigo'];


            $total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT codigo FROM detalleinventarioinicial WHERE substr(codigo,1,5)='$c' and idcolegio=$idcolegio"));
    if($total==0){


    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO detalleinventarioinicial (idingreso,nro,codigo,descripcion,unidad,cantidad,marca,serie,color,tipo,procedencia,docingreso,numdocingreso,estado,observacion,idcolegio,idusuario,modificacion) VALUES ('$idingreso','$nro','{$codigo}001','$descripcion','$unidad','$cantidad','$marca','$serie','$color','$tipo','$procedencia','$docingreso','$numdocingreso','$estado','$observacion','$idcolegio','$idusuario','$modificacion')");
    header('location: inventario.php');
    }else{


    $e=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT MAX(codigo) +1 max FROM detalleinventarioinicial  where substr(codigo,1,5)='$codigo' and idcolegio=$idcolegio GROUP by descripcion");
        $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($e);

        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO detalleinventarioinicial (idingreso,nro,codigo,descripcion,unidad,cantidad,marca,serie,color,tipo,procedencia,docingreso,numdocingreso,estado,observacion,idcolegio,idusuario,modificacion) VALUES ('$idingreso','$nro','{$d['max']}','$descripcion','$unidad','$cantidad','$marca','$serie','$color','$tipo','$procedencia','$docingreso','$numdocingreso','$estado','$observacion','$idcolegio','$idusuario','$modificacion')");
     header('location: inventario.php');
```